# CNAME to direct one domain to another

Tags: cname

I have three unique domains. Let's call them `domain1.example`, `domain2.example` and `domain3.example`. They all need to go to the same website, which I am serving with `domain1.example`.

Can I just create CNAME records like this?

```
domain2.example    CNAME    domain1.example
domain3.example    CNAME    domain1.example
```

Or do CNAMEs only work for subdomains (i.e. `www.domain2.example`)?

Comment: I am not running mail or any other services with domain2.com or domain3.com.

Comment: Presumably you still want to have `domain2` and `domain3` in the address bar? Are you using name-based Virtual Hosts (ie. a shared server)? In which case, setting a `CNAME` record isn't the only thing you'll need to do.

Comment: `CNAME` can not exist at apex, so you can say they work only for subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do this.

For domain 1, you should have an A record that points an IP address to `domain1.example`. That is a given.

For domain 2 & 3, you can use a CNAME to point `domain2.example` to `domain1.example` and `domain3.example` to `domain1.example`.

You may also need to use a CNAME for any `www` version of any site. The process is the same. You would point `www.domain1.example` to `domain1.example` and point `www.domain2.example` to `domain1.example` and `www.domain3.example` to `domain1.example`.

Just know that there may be an issue with duplicate content. To avoid this, you would use a canonical tag to correct this.

You can find more information than you want at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en ,however, example code for what you need exists under the header *Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element*. With this code, you would be pointing your content page to itself using the domain 1 domain name.

Comment: "Yes. You can do this." No, you can't do this with `CNAME` records as asked by OP because you can not have a CNAME record at the apex since the CNAME can not coexist with any other record , and apex obviously always have NS and SOA records, so you can NOT do `example.com. CNAME example.net.`. Various providers have specific local proprietary solutions to basically do the above, often called ALIAS or ANAME or TARGET or whatever else. They are however not standardized. You can have a `CNAME` on  `www` of course.